# Como detectar que no se han enviado mensajes en cierto tiempo desde el cliente al servidor tcp java

Tags: java, tcp

Como detectar que el cliente no ha mandando mensajes durante x tiempo al servidor en java, el servidor escucha mensajes del cliente, el cliente manda mensajes cada x tiempo de forma aleatoria. Cuando se exeda el tiempo maximo el servidor debera mandar un mensaje por pantalla.

He probado con esto

*Servidor hilo*

````
import java.net.*;
import java.util.logging.*;

public class ServidorHilo extends Thread {

    private Socket socket;
    private DataOutputStream dos;
    private DataInputStream dis;
    private int idSessio;

    public ServidorHilo(Socket socket, int id) {
        this.socket = socket;
        this.idSessio = id;
        try {
            dos = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
            dis = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(ServidorHilo.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

        long inicio = System.currentTimeMillis();
        while (true) {
            String mensaje = "";
            try {
                
                mensaje = dis.readUTF();
                if (mensaje.equals("mensaje")) {
                    System.out.println("" + this.idSessio + ": mensaje");
                    inicio = System.currentTimeMillis();
                }
                long fin = System.currentTimeMillis();
                double tiempo = (double) ((fin - inicio) / 1000);
                if (tiempo>=8) {
                    System.out.println("Error en "+this.idSessio+"");
                }
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(ServidorHilo.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }

        }

    }
}```
````

Comment: El servidor está bloqueado a la espera de un nuevo mensaje (`dis.readUTF()`) por lo que mientras no llegue, no seguirá ejecutando el código , por qué no creas una clase auxiliar a la que el servidor pueda notificar cuando recibe un mensaje y que lo único que haga es cada X tiempo comparar si se ha excedido el tiempo máximo de espera desde la última vez que le notificó?

Comment: En linea con el comentario de @Benito-B podes implementarlo con un LinkedHashMap (x q vas a estar agregando y removiendo elementos) en el Thread principal, usas como key el nombre del Thread y el value seria la hora en que llegó el último mensaje. Después solo tenes que recorrer el hashmap usando su key set para ver cuanto pasó desde que se recibió el último mensaje.